# Mounting pull-up/exercise beam in corner above window

Tags: wood, joists, load-bearing, beam

I'm considering mounting a beam for climbing exercise equipment similar to what is pictured below (see [here](http://rockclimberstrainingmanual.com/2014/03/06/hows-your-hang/) for complete details):
[image: Hangboard mount]

The set up (in my case) would consist of two 20" 2x8 base boards each mounted ~40" from the corner attached to two studs each via 5/16" lag screws. Between the base boards would run an additional 56x2x8 main beam mounted to the base boards via angled joist hangers. However, in my case, one of the base boards would need to fixed to the wall above a window.

My question is: **Would it be a horrible idea to mount a base board above a window?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no problem doing so. In fact, you probably have the best substructure there. You'll find a 2x6 or larger header either directly above the window or below the top wall plate. You should also find "cripple" or "pin" studs on standard centers over or under the header.

Be aware that some header designs leave a 1/2" or larger insulated gap between the framing and the drywall if the load-bearing members are sandwiched together and installed at the outside of the wall thickness. You could potentially cause significant drywall damage by pulling your lumber tight with bolts. Press firmly on the drywall where you plan on bolting to feel for flex, then proceed slowly when tightening, keeping an eye out for movement.

Comment: You can easily avoid any trouble with the header by googling up a picture of "king and jack studs". The "king" is full height and 99.994% guaranteed to be exactly where you expect it.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem you may find is accidently kicking in the glass when using the exercise equipment. Other than that the wall studs are spaced 16" O/C only shorter above the header spanning the windows' width.

Comment: Haha true--will have to avoid that